# Permission Error while importing requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-11

When I am trying to

**import requests** i get the following error

PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Users\…\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2o4693yn'

How may I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

I’m using python 3.10 on windows 11

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by removing two *.pth files that were created when I had installed python-certifi-win32. deleting these two files prevents python-certifi-win32 from loading when python is run.

Location of the files

C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages
Files:

python-certifi-win32-init.pth
distutils-precedence.pth